# VueJS: Calling parent method from children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
var CompA = {
    ...
    methods: {
        parentMethod(){

        }
    }
}
var CompB = {
    extends: CompA,
    ...
    render(h) {
        return this.parentMethod();
    }
}
```

How to call the `parentMethod`? Its not working in `this` scope.

Comment: `this.parentMethod` does work

Comment: I agree with @CodinCat. The method can be called. In order to render something you would need to return a vnode from the `parentMethod`.